# ViewPager lags onMeasure

Tags: android, performance, android-viewpager, onmeasure

When ViewPager has 3 pages it works ok, but when pages count becomes about 10 app lags. Each page has nested custom views

Logs saying:

```
onMeasure time too long, this =android.support.v4.view.ViewPager...
```

Why it happens depends on pages count? Setting off screen pages (pager.offscreenPageLimit = 3) doesnt help also

Comment: Have tried updating to ViewPager2? https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2

Comment: @Traendy gonna try now thanks, i should update whole project to androidX, right?

Comment: Android support library is no longer maintained. You should update your project if you are continuing to work on it in the future.

Comment: by default viewPager loading 2-3 pages, so if has 10 pages it should not be a problem. Could it be badly scaled images?

Comment: @AntonisRadz no images on pages

Comment: what about recyclerViews?

Comment: @AntonisRadz only scrollView with children views

Comment: so could it be because of to large dataset? If it is large you need to use RecyclerView. Its clear that some of the pages requires to much performance look in to that, not in to ViewPager